# Django application deployment problem and error logs

Tags: django, deployment, vps

I am trying to deploy my django application to VPS but I get 505- Internal Server Error and it is normal for the first time.

However, the admin of the VPS server do not allow me to see the error logs of the Apache Server. In such situation, is there any way to view the real error messagges/logs  ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you deployed your app with `DEBUG=True` maybe the error message can help you.

Your vps admin should give to you at least a copy of your log files.. i don't see another way..